# Square of order of a Sylow p-subgroup in the nonabelian simple groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Is it true that for all Sylow subgroups $P$ of a nonabelian simple group $G$ that $|P|^2 < |G|$?

If $P$ is abelian, this is an easy consequence of Brodkey's theorem (Suppose that a Sylow $p$-subgroup of a finite group $G$ is abelian. Then there exits Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ and $T$ such that $P\bigcap T=O_{p}(G)$).

Comment: I don't understand your argument for the case where $P$ is abelian. So then there exist two Sylow $p$-subgroups such that $P \cap T = 1$. Why does that imply $|P|^2 < |G|$?

Comment: $P$ is not abelian.

Comment: @spin: When $P$ is abelian consider $PT$ that is a subgroup of $G$, since $PT=TP$.

Comment: $PT$ is not a subgroup since $G$ is simple. But as a subset it has order $|P| |T| = |P|^2$, which must be $< |G|$. I see now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, although all the proofs use the classification of finite simple groups.

Your question was a conjecture of Brauer, which was proven in the 
following paper (theorem 3.6 in there).

> Kimmerle, Wolfgang; Lyons, Richard; Sandling, Robert; Teague, David N.
>   *Composition factors from the group ring and Artin's theorem on orders of simple groups*. Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 60 (1990), no. 1, 89–122.

It was also proven later by Zenkov and Mazurov in this paper:

> Zenkov, V. I.; Mazurov, V. D. *On the intersection of Sylow subgroups in finite groups*. Algebra and Logic 35 (1996), no. 4, 236–240

The main result of Zenkov and Mazurov states that if $G$ is a finite simple group and $p$ is a prime dividing $|G|$, then some pair $P$,$Q$ of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ have trivial intersection. Then $PQ$ is a subset of $G$ with order $|P|^2 < |G|$.

Finally, it turns out that actually something more general is true. Vdovin has proven that if $N$ is a nilpotent subgroup of any nonabelian simple group $G$, then $|N|^2 < |G|$. See this paper:

> Vdovin, E. P. *Large nilpotent subgroups of finite simple groups*. Algebra and Logic 39 (2000), no. 5, 301–312 [link to article](http://math.nsc.ru/~vdovin/Papers/larnilpeng.pdf)